# JasperReport Studio / JRXML / JasperReports number format of table element

Tags: jasper-reports

following problem in JasperReport Studio:

I designed a query, I designed, inserted a table element in the Report but when I preview the data numbers look like this:

3.0083728739827928739279

I would like them to look like this:

3.01

In a  element I can just add a pattern. For example:

```
<textField pattern="#,##0.###">
```

This (i.e.: jr:table pattern="#,##0.###") does not work with a table element.

So how do I format a table?

Thanks and best regards, Joachim

edit 25/07/2018:

one solution is to add the pattern to each textField -element within the jr:table -element by editing the JRMXL code, still I would like to know how to reach this setting via a GUI (i.e. JasperReport Studio)

Comment: You should post the small *jrxml* to reproduce the issue. It should work at jr:table

Comment: To display your data I guess you are using cells with `textField` elements in it ? Why not having the `pattern` attribute on those `textField` ?

Comment: Thanks matthiasbe, you are completly right. Edited the question...

Comment: Your question is unclear, you like something that format all columns in table? All columns are numbers? Anyway AFIK it's not possible you need to define pattern for each column

Answer (score 0):

Set the Pattern using Java decimal Formate. 
Example

```
<field name="data" class="java.lang.Double"/>

"<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new DecimalFormat("0.0").format($F{data})]]></textFieldExpression>"
```

I hope Its properly work for you.